# Nginx: All Pages Return 404 Not Found except Home Page

Tags: magento2, php, configuration, nginx

I'm using `Magento 2.4.4`, I've set up the existing project, but all page goes to 404 except the homepage. I'm using Nginx for the first time so still figuring out how to configure it.

**/etc/nginx/sites-available/ruralking.local:**

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name ruralking.local www.ruralking.local;
    root /var/www/ruralking.local/pub;

    index index.html index.htm index.php;

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
    }

    location ~ \.php$ {
        include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php8.1-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_buffers 16 256k;
        fastcgi_buffer_size 256k;
    }

    location ~ /\.ht {
        deny all;
    }
}
```

Comment: What happens if you try ``site.com/index.php/path/here``?

Comment: still goes to 404.

Comment: It seems that Nginx conf for Magento is different.

Answer (score 0):

Your nginx use the pub folder as document root folder. [See the magento docs for more information.](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/install-gde/tutorials/change-docroot-to-pub.html)
In this case, you have to set the following node to the array in you environment file (app/etc/env.php):

```
'directories' => [
  'document_root_is_pub' => true,
],
```

Did you set this node?

Comment: yes, it's included in `env.php`